# Non-relational databases (NoSQL) for small to medium sized applications

Tags: nosql, amazon-simpledb, non-relational-database

The benefits of a non-relational database (such as a key-value pair storage) are evident when used in large scale datasets (google, facebook, linkedin). How do you think small to medium sized applications can  benefit from using non-relational databases?

Comment: I admit to having no real experience with this, but I'd like to see some links backing up that claim or at least explaining what the alternatives are. I also agree that it should probably be community wiki.

Comment: Would you please define "non-relational" as something other than "isn't relational"?   Otherwise any ad hoc scheme for storing data qualifies.

Comment: you are right, Ira. I will change the question

Comment: ...and converted into a community wiki, thanks jldupont and Platinum Azure

Comment: Keep in mind that 'non-relation' doesn't just mean the new NoSQL style data stores. There are other styles that have been around a long time, like Network, Hierarchical, and Object DBs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IBM Mainframes have had "non-relational" databases since the 60s (hierarchial databases such as IMS + variants).  These databases are still in use because they are extremely fast and handle huge scale well.

The point of relational databases was to provide a regular, relatively abstract method for storing and retrieving data in which the tuning can be done relatively independently of the data model (not true for IMS).   They were designed rather in reaction to the inability to reorganize hiearchical databases easily. The upside is nice organization; the downside is medium, not high performance.

Google provides scalable storage and MapReduce to handle scale.  It isn't relational.

There was a huge push early in the last decade to store data in XML, in essentially hiearchical form because XML is implicitly hierarchical.  That was a huge mistake IMHO, because it repeated the inconvenience of heirarchical databases, but had none of the performance.  I'm not very surprised this movement seems to have pretty much died.

Most of the practical push to non-relational seems to me to be towards performance and scale.  I don't see how this helps "small" applications much.

People have proposed, but not done a lot of practical data management using knowledge-based schemes.   Doug Lenat's [CYC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc) comes to mind here.  The ability of the database
to help an application draw non-obvious conclusions strikes me a very interesting for "small" applications that are trying be "smart".  But there aren't a lot of these yet.

Answer (score 2):

The sweet spot of using a NoSQL database at that scale is when the database model (key-value, document, etc.) is a good match to the application's needs and the advanced relational functionality is not needed.

At the small end of the spectrum, performance is a non issue because just about everything is fast. Storage engines are a non issue, if you don't need a sophisticated query engine, the lack of SQL support is a non issue.

You are left with how well it fits and how easy it is to use. Honestly though, tooling does become an issue. Relational database tooling is mature, NoSQL tooling is less feature rich and less battle hardened. Too often it is roll-your-own tooling. Definitely consider what tools you'd be giving up and how much you need them.

There is an additional slate of advantages for smaller projects when considering a NoSQL service (like Amazon SimpleDB and Microsoft Azure) as compared to a product. If you only have to pay for what you use and you don't use much, it can be cheaper than running a dedicated server, going all the way down to free for something like the SimpleDB free usage tier.

You also avoid some of the server and database maintenance costs. This can be a big win if you don't have a DBA, or when your DBAs are already over worked. Of course you'll still have admin work to do, but it is significantly reduced, and typically simpler.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to graph databases (like [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) - a project I'm involved in) they excel at [scaling to complexity](http://blogs.neotechnology.com/emil/2009/11/nosql-scaling-to-size-and-scaling-to-complexity.html). This means, they provide ["better substrates for modeling business domains"](http://www.viget.com/extend/nosql-misconceptions/) (see [The State of NoSQL](http://www.slideshare.net/bscofield/the-state-of-nosql), also by [Ben Scofield](http://benscofield.com/), too). As I see it, this is very important in small to medium sized apps.

This may be better explained through examples, so here's some links to example apps/domain modeling:

- [Access control lists the graph
  database way](http://blog.neo4j.org/2010/02/access-control-lists-graph-database-way.html)
- [Social networks in the database: using a graph database](http://blog.neo4j.org/2009/09/social-networks-in-database-using-graph.html)
- [Domain modeling gallery](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Domain_Modeling_Gallery)

Answer (score 0):

The question perhaps requires a bit more context... assuming a Python environment, consider the tutorial at  the y_serial project: http://yserial.sourceforge.net/

NoSQL is not merely adopted for reasons of scalability. Serialization (of any arbitrary Python object) and persistence are very convenient at any scale -- so consider the key-value system as one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the problems with a RDBMS is that you need to spend effort mapping your programming languages domain models to the relational schema of your RDBMS. This effort is usually spent configuring your ORM layer.

With NoSQL databases you are not forced to map your objects to a relational model and in most cases your objects are serialized as-is. Because of the lack of an intermediary schema, [data migrations and versioning become easier](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/MigrationsUsingSchemalessNoSql).

Another benefit is scalability and performance. Since most of the time your data is received by 'keys' effectively everything uses and index. Trivial sharding is possible by doing a % (MOD) on the key against the number of your available NoSQL instances providing natural data partitioning which is crucial for sharding.

If you're interested in seeing how developing with a NoSQL differs from a RDBMS, I have a tutorial where I show how to go about [designing a simple blog application using Redis](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/DesigningNoSqlDatabase).

Answer (score 0):

If you match up a few common PaaS cloud services like a Key-Value store, a BLOB store, and a Message Queue store you have some handy tools that can free small application developers from the tyranny of the DBA and the infrastructure folks.

Today small developers often resort to Jet MDBs.  Why?  Easy, shared access is as easy as storing the MDB file on a file share visible to the entire application community.  When they can get away with it (i.e. get the necessary support from the gatekeepers) they might use SQL Server Express, MySQL, etc.

Sadly those gatekeepers can be pretty hostile to deal with in a large organization.  Mention a "database" and suddenly you face the DBA gang and associated delays, application reviews, prioritization, etc.  Mention needing a server and you face that other firing squad.

Using a NoSQL solution and related cloud services can eliminate a ton of this if you don't need an RDBMS.

For one thing, all that's really required is an account with a public cloud provider.  This is something that becomes fairly easy once the concept has been approved.  And easier for you as a developer once you've been approved and assigned an account, though of course there are the usual bookkeeping issues.

But let's even set that aside.  What if your organization implemented a private cloud for such uses?  Lots of the issues of outside billing go away, data insecurity worries go away, etc.

Such a thing could be implemented and provisioned in a semi-anonymous fashion, almost as easily as administering file shares.  The anonymity comes in because once you've been approved to develop on the in-house cloud nobody needs to nitpick the details of your activities using it any more than they need to examine a request before you can create a file on an existing file share.

Obviously there would be storage and CPU quotas to manage.  Nobody can afford to just keep scaling up indefinately.  Rogue applications might consume vast quantities of resources.  So what you need is some sort of quota system to cap usage.  Whether this is monitored by infrastructure folks is an implementation decision, or it might be treated just like file share use: run out and somebody yells at the programmer who in turn looks into it and requests more if appropriate (or fixes his bugs).

But you end up with "utility computing" and by "using no SQL" you don't incur the cost (and issues) of dealing with DBAs.  They can still sit quietly surfing the Web in their big offices while you get some work done.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SimpleDB can be useful for those who need a non-relational database for storage of smaller, non-structural data. Amazon SimpleDB has restricted storage size to 10GB per domain. Amazon SimpleDB offers simplicity and flexibility. SimpleDB automatically indexes all data. Amazon SimpleDB pricing is based on your actual box usage. You can store any UTF-8 string data in Amazon SimpleDB.